# Using "oscillator" rather than crystal for MCU

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, crystal

I'm kinda new to this so the name is based on Digikey. I have a PIC24FV32KA304 and I want to put an external oscillator of 32mhz. I found out that an oscillator [like this one](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/ASFL1-32.000MHZ-L-T/535-10823-1-ND/2624401) is a bit cheaper than say, [like this one](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/ECS-320-8-30B-CKM/XC1846CT-ND/2781971).

This is the configuration I thought using a crystal : 
  [image]

My question is, if I want to use an oscillator rather than a crystal, how do I connect the output of it to pins 30 and 31 ?

Comment: Just as a note: the oscillator takes a lot of current (20-45mA), if you connect a crystal it will likely be a lot less (drive level is max 100 µW). That might be important for some applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It connects to CLKI (the "I" is for "In") and you configure the device to use an external clock source instead of a crystal.

Comment: I suppose I can configure the other pin as an I/O ?

Comment: You should be able to. Unless you want to cascade the clock to another device.

Comment: @GmodCake you want to have a look at the errata, I've encountered quite a few devices where it wouldn't work correctly as GPIO if the other pin is used as clock in.

Comment: @Arsenal I'll take note of that, but I think I will leave it unconnected anyway